# Concatanating strings with echo

Tags: php, string, echo

Hello I have a list of words that i want to wrap around the following characters but i can't seem to get it to work

```
List of words, which are form variables
=======================================
fname lname address city state zip
```

i want to wrap each of those in the following and be able to display it to me on a page with echo

```
<</T(fname)/V('.$fname.')>>
```

I have the following loop:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$list  = $_POST["listVars"];
$each = explode(" ", $list);
    foreach ($each as &$value) {
     echo "<</T" .$value. ")/V('.$" .$value. ".')>>";
}
}
```

Comment: Is an error being generated? What results are you seeing?

Comment: If you're wanting to echo `<` and `>` you'll have to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` PHP is trying to figure out what to do with those `< >`

Comment: why there is a '&' right before '$value'?

Comment: the &lt; and &gt; worked perfect, thanks a lot guys!!!

Comment: echo '&lt;&lt;/T' .$value. ')/V($&rsquo;'.$value. '&rsquo;)&gt;&gt;';

Answer (score 2):

For echo character $ escape it in string.

For example `echo "\$";`